# C programming error: expected '(' before 'move'

Tags: c, function, parameters, compiler-errors, compilation

I am trying to pass a string parameter into my function, but I am getting an error telling me to put "(" before move.

```
void movement(char move) {
    if move == "CCW"{
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD5);    // drive pin PD5 high, motor 1 bkwd
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD6);    // drive pin PD6 low, motor 1 bkwd
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD3);    // drive pin PD3 low, motor 2 fwd
        PORTB |= (1 << PORTB3);    // drive pin PB3 high, motor 2 fwd
    }
    else if move == "CW"{
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD5);    // drive pin PD5 low, motor 1 fwd
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD6);    // drive pin PD6 high, motor 1 fwd
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD3);    // drive pin PD3 high, motor 2 bkwd
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB3);    // drive pin PB3 low, motor 2 bkwd
    }
    else if move == "F"{
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD5);    // drive pin PD5 low, motor 1
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD6);    // drive pin PD6 high, motor 1
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD3);    // drive pin PD3 low , motor 2
        PORTB |= (1 << PORTB3);    // drive pin PB3 high, motor 2
    }
    else if move == "R"{
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD5);    // drive pin PD5 high, motor 1
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD6);    // drive pin PD6 low, motor 1
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD3);    // drive pin PD3 high, motor 2
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB3);    // drive pin PB3 low, motor 2
    }
    else {
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD5) | (1 << PORTD6); //m1 brake
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD3); // drive pin PD3 high, m2 brake
        PORTB |= (1 << PORTB3); // drive pin PB3 high, m2 brake
    }
    end
}
```

Anything look wrong here?

Comment: Yup. There's no `(` before `move` :-). The syntax of an if statement is `if ( expr ) statement` or `if ( expr ) statement else statement`. The parentheses around the expression are required.

Comment: and your `move` variable is just char, so you cant compare it with a string by `move == "R"`, in C, you have to use char* for string and use strcmp() to compare

Comment: if you are told by the compiler to put a `(` before `move`, then put it to see what happens!!!! :)  that `(` is actually needed there!  (in all `if` statements)

Answer (score 1):

C's `if` and `else if` statements should be formatted like

```
if (move == "CCW") {
    ... 
}
else if (move == "CW") {
    ...
}
```

Also, C doesn't require `end` to end an if-else block.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, the 'test expression' in `if` (and `else if`) statements in C ***must*** be enclosed in parentheses; this is an immutable aspect of the [language's syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/if). Furthermore, there is no `end` statement in C – the scope of code blocks delimited by curly braces (`{ ... }`) ends 'naturally' at the closing brace.

Another *major* issue in your code is the nature of the `move` parameter of your `movement` function: You say, *"I am trying to pass a string parameter into my function..."* but what you are *actually* passing is a single character. To pass a (C-style, nul-terminated) *string*, the argument should be declared as `char* move` (that is, a pointer to the first character of the string).

With this fixed, you still have problems in your comparisons. You can't compare strings, either to each other or to constants (literals like `"CCW"`) using the `==` operator. Instead, you need to use the [`strcmp` standard library function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) and check that the returned value is (or isn't) zero.

Here's a fixed version of your function:

```c
#include <string.h> // For the definition of the "strcmp" function

void movement(char* move) // Parameter should be a pointer-to-char (C-style string)
{
    if (strcmp(move, "CCW") == 0) { // Cannot use "==" to compare strings
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD5);    // drive pin PD5 high, motor 1 bkwd
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD6);    // drive pin PD6 low, motor 1 bkwd
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD3);    // drive pin PD3 low, motor 2 fwd
        PORTB |= (1 << PORTB3);    // drive pin PB3 high, motor 2 fwd
    }
    else if (strcmp(move, "CW") == 0) {
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD5);    // drive pin PD5 low, motor 1 fwd
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD6);    // drive pin PD6 high, motor 1 fwd
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD3);    // drive pin PD3 high, motor 2 bkwd
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB3);    // drive pin PB3 low, motor 2 bkwd
    }
    else if (strcmp(move, "F") == 0) { // Only one (non-null) character, but still a string
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD5);    // drive pin PD5 low, motor 1
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD6);    // drive pin PD6 high, motor 1
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD3);    // drive pin PD3 low , motor 2
        PORTB |= (1 << PORTB3);    // drive pin PB3 high, motor 2
    }
    else if (!strcmp(move, "R")) { // We can use !x as an 'abbreviation' for x == 0
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD5);    // drive pin PD5 high, motor 1
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD6);    // drive pin PD6 low, motor 1
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD3);    // drive pin PD3 high, motor 2
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB3);    // drive pin PB3 low, motor 2
    }
    else {
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD5) | (1 << PORTD6); //m1 brake
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD3); // drive pin PD3 high, m2 brake
        PORTB |= (1 << PORTB3); // drive pin PB3 high, m2 brake
    }
    // No "end" statement in C
}
```

Note that, for this code to work, the passed `move` argument **must** be a pointer to the first character of a [nul-terminated string](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm), because that is what the `strcmp` function expects its two arguments to be; your string literals (like `"CW"`) will be nul-terminated, because the compiler will add the required zero-character on your behalf.

Please feel free to ask for any further clarification and/or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of **if else if ** statement is

```
if (expression){
    ...
}
else if (expression){
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

so you need to **change your code as**

```
void movement(char move) {
    if (move == "CCW"){
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD5);    // drive pin PD5 high, motor 1 bkwd
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD6);    // drive pin PD6 low, motor 1 bkwd
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD3);    // drive pin PD3 low, motor 2 fwd
        PORTB |= (1 << PORTB3);    // drive pin PB3 high, motor 2 fwd
    }
    else if (move == "CW"){
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD5);    // drive pin PD5 low, motor 1 fwd
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD6);    // drive pin PD6 high, motor 1 fwd
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD3);    // drive pin PD3 high, motor 2 bkwd
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB3);    // drive pin PB3 low, motor 2 bkwd
    }
    else if (move == "F"){
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD5);    // drive pin PD5 low, motor 1
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD6);    // drive pin PD6 high, motor 1
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD3);    // drive pin PD3 low , motor 2
        PORTB |= (1 << PORTB3);    // drive pin PB3 high, motor 2
    }
    else if (move == "R"){
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD5);    // drive pin PD5 high, motor 1
        PORTD &= ~(1 << PORTD6);    // drive pin PD6 low, motor 1
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD3);    // drive pin PD3 high, motor 2
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PORTB3);    // drive pin PB3 low, motor 2
    }
    else {
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD5) | (1 << PORTD6); //m1 brake
        PORTD |= (1 << PORTD3); // drive pin PD3 high, m2 brake
        PORTB |= (1 << PORTB3); // drive pin PB3 high, m2 brake
    }
}
```

**Note:** There is no end statement in C for closing the if else statement